# SUM values based on Distinct Values of another column

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table :

```
Sales ID
100   a
100   a
103.5 c
105   d
105   d
```

....
I want to simply get the value **308.5**( which is 100+103.5+105, the unique values).

I've tried this:

```
select sum(case when rownum=1 then sales end) from 
(select sales,id, row_number() over (partition  by id) as rownum from table) subquery
```

But every time I refresh it I'm getting a different value.

What is the alternative way?

Comment: Let's say after next refresh, you got 100, a and 101, a, how do you want to do the calculation? 100+101+103.5+105 or 100+103.5+105?

Answer (score 0):

> But every time I refresh it I'm getting a different value.

That would suggest that the underlying data is changing -- which is unlikely on Vertica.  Or more likely that you have multiple values for a single id.  You can test the latter:

```
select id, count(distinct sales)
from t
where min(sales) <> max(sales);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery for distinct sales

```
    select sum(t.distinct_sales)
    from  (
        select distinct Sales as distinct_sales
        FROM my_table
    ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to de-dupe by running a SELECT DISTINCT first, and SUM()-ming afterwards. Like so:

```
WITH
-- this is your input - don't use in real query
input(Sales,ID) AS (
          SELECT 100,'a'
UNION ALL SELECT 100,'a'
UNION ALL SELECT 103.5,'c'
UNION ALL SELECT 105,'d'
UNION ALL SELECT 105,'d'
)
, -- < - replace this comma with "WITH", and start the real query here ...
uq (sales) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    sales
  FROM input
)
SELECT
  SUM(sales)
FROM uq;
-- out   SUM  
-- out -------
-- out  308.5
-- out (1 row)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (1 row): 7.795 ms. All rows formatted: 7.826 ms


-- if ( 100 , 'a' ) is different from ( 100 , 'd' ), then it would be the below

WITH
-- this is your input - don't use in real query
input(Sales,ID) AS (
          SELECT 100,'a'
UNION ALL SELECT 100,'a'
UNION ALL SELECT 103.5,'c'
UNION ALL SELECT 105,'d'
UNION ALL SELECT 105,'d'
)
, -- < - replace this comma with "WITH", and start the real query here ...
uq (sales,id) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    sales
  , id
  FROM input
)
SELECT
  SUM(sales)
FROM uq;
-- out   SUM  
-- out -------
-- out  308.5
-- out (1 row)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (1 row): 11.084 ms. All rows formatted: 11.117 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the sum of sales from the distinct pairs of sales and id:

```
select sum(t.sales) from (
  select distinct sales, id
  from table
) t
```

or:

```
select sum(t.sales) from (
  select sales from table
  group by sales, id
) t
```